# Restoring One Node From an Availability Group With Recovery Pending

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, recovery

I have an availability group that is no longer valid (one node is gone). If I connect directly to the remaining node, the databases are all shown as recovery pending. In the Availability Group, the AG is listed as resolving. When I look at the dashboard for the availability group, I see 2 errors:

1. Availability replica is disconnected
2. Availability replica does not have a healthy role
   and I also see a warning:
3. Data synchronization state of some availability database is not healthy.

I don't see any mention of Node2 anywhere in the interface, but it is certainly unavailable. How can I take Node 1 out of the AG and recover that data?

When I click on the Failover Wizard, I get the following error:

The local node is not part of quorum and is unable to initiate a failover. This could be caused by one of the following reasons:

•   The local node is not able to communicate with the WSFC cluster.

•   No quorum set exists across the WSFC cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The DBs will come online once you resolve the 'RESOLVING' state of the AG. Check the cluster in Failover Cluster Manager, the issue may be that the AG resource can't come online due to a lack of quorum (since the second node is missing). Once the AG resource is online it should bring the DBs online automatically then you can safely deconstruct the AG configuration.